# Difference between "C++ void Pointer" and "C# var"

Tags: c#, c++

While learning C#, this question came to my mind. What is the difference between `void` and `var`?
Here are the two example I would like to share:

```
void * voidInt = (void *) 7;
void * voidChar = (void *) 'F';
void * voidCharArray = (void *) "AbcString";
```

And this is example of `var`:

```
var varInt = 7;
var varChar = 'F';
var varCharArray = "AbcString";
```

- Is `void` an *anonymous datatype*?
- If yes, then what is the major
  difference between `var` and `void`?

Can someone help me clear this situation?

Comment: `var` is purely syntactic sugar.. Complier tries its best to infer the strong type implicitly. It is as if, you had specified the specific type in source code.. but were lazy to type it yourself. Try setting `var x = null;` and see the difference.

Comment: @VikasGupta it gave error: Error `Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable`

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Exactly.. :) the key part here is "implicitly-typed local variable" you could assign null to void pointer, but the same is not true for var.. because var is completely different.. Enough has been said below in answer and other comments.. so I'll skip the rest

Comment: Note: C# supports pointers, including `void*` pointers - in an `unsafe` block. Ultimately, the C# equivalent of `void*` is: `void*`

Comment: There is a very close analogy to C#'s `var foo = some_expression;` in C++11/14, and that's `auto foo = some_expression;`. In both cases, the variable `foo` is strongly typed, but that type is automatically inferred at compile time from the type of `some_expression` (which might well be an expression).

Comment: Should be tagged 'c'. C++ now has `auto`, which is similar to `var`.

Comment: @Macke Another question should be asked for `C` language I think.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The other answers here are pretty good but I think they do not get clearly to the fundamentals. It is the fundamentals you are confused about, so let's address those.

- A *variable* is a *storage location* that contains a *value*.
- A *variable* is associated with a *type*.
- A *local variable* has a *name*.

So `voidInt`, `voidChar`, `voidCharArray`, `varInt`, `varChar` and `varCharArray` are all *variables*, and they all have *types* associated with them. Each variable can be *assigned* a value of that type or *produce* a value of that type, depending on whether the variable is being written to or read from.

OK, so now what are pointers?

- A type has a corresponding *pointer type*. (Note that in unsafe C# only the *unmanaged types* have corresponding pointer types.)
- The `void *` type is a special pointer type.
- A *pointer* is a value.
- A pointer of type `T*` may be *dereferenced* to produce a *variable* of type `T`. `T*` must not be `void*`.
- A pointer may be explicitly converted to or from any integral type, though these operations are permitted to lose information and are dependent on implementation details.
- Any pointer value may be implicitly converted to `void*`.
- Any `void*` value may be explicitly converted to any pointer type value.

And what is `var` in C#?

- `var` is a "syntactic sugar" that tells the compiler to deduce the type of the variable from the initialzier rather than requiring that it be written out.

And what are "anonymous types" in C#?

- Some expressions in C# have a type that is not declared and has no name; these are known as the "anonymous" types.

So now we can look at your program and see what each line does.

```
void * voidInt = (void *) 7;
```

`voidInt` is a variable of type `void*`. The value assigned to it is the conversion of the integer 7 to a pointer, which is almost certainly a garbage pointer on any modern operating system.  This code is essentially nonsensical.

More sensible code would be:

```
int myInt = 7;
int* intPtr = &myInt;
void* voidInt = intPtr;
```

This means that `myInt` is a variable which holds the value `7`, `intPtr` is a variable which holds a pointer; when that pointer is dereferenced it produces variable `myInt`. `voidInt` is a variable which holds any pointer, and the value read from `intPtr` is a pointer. So now `voidInt` and `intPtr` both hold a pointer to variable `myInt`.

```
void * voidChar = (void *) 'F';
```

Same thing here. The character `F` is treated as a number and converted to a pointer value, which is stored in the variable. This is not sensible. Sensible code would be something like:

```
char myChar = 'F';
void *voidChar = &myChar;
```

But this makes perfect sense:

```
void * voidCharArray = (void *) "AbcString";
```

A string literal in C++ is convertible to a `char*` which is a pointer to the storage for the first character, and that pointer is convertible to `void*`.

What about this?

```
var varInt = 7;
var varChar = 'F';
var varCharArray = "AbcString";
```

This is just a pleasant way to write

```
int varInt = 7;
char varChar = 'F';
string varCharArray = "AbcString";
```

Each variable has its given type, and each assignment stores a value of that type in the variable.

What about anonymous types?

```
var anon = new { X = 123, Y = 456 };
```

This makes a variable of anonymous type, where the anonymous type has two properties X and Y both of type `int`. The type has no name, so there is no way to write out the type in the declaration, hence `var` must be used.

The key thing here is to make sure that you have a grasp of the *fundamentals*: pointers are *values*, they may be *dereferenced*, and doing so produces a *variable*. Since pointers are *values* they may themselves be stored in *variables* of pointer type. This has almost nothing to do with `var`, which is a pleasant way in C# to make the compiler do the work of figuring out what type a variable should have.

Comment: This is something really good. Awesome @Eric. I think I'll have to change the correct answer.

Answer (score 18):

`void` and `var` do not really have anything in common:

- [void](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type) (as used by pointer variables in C and C++) means an unspecified (not a definite) type. `void*` aren't permitted* in managed C# (although a very weak type, such as an `object` reference might be a close approximation). Generally, `void*` types need to be re-cast in order to be useful.
- However `void` *return types* from a method / function mean the same
  in both languages, which is to convey that there is *no return value* (like `Unit` in Scala)
- In contrast, `var` in C# defines an [implicitly typed variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) - the variable still has a strong type, but the actual type is inferred from the right hand side at compile time.

e.g.

```
var v1 = "Foo"; // v1 is a string, because it is inferred from the right hand side
var v2 = XDocument.Parse(@"c:\temp\foo.xml"); // v2 is the return type of the function
```

`var` is often required when using anonymous types - this is probably where you've made the connection between `var` and anonymous types:

```
var v3 = new { Name = "Foo", Value = 123};  // v3 is strongly typed, anonymous class.
```

`var` is especially useful for assigning variables to the return values of LINQ expressions, where the types can be quite complex:

```
var v3 = db.Persons
      .Join(db.Cities, p => p.CityId, c => c.Id, (p, c) => new {Person = p, City = c})
      .GroupBy(pc => pc.City.Name);
```

<sub>* Actually, that's not entirely true, you can use void* in C# with [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx)</sub>

**Edit**

One further thing worth mentioning, that as of C#6, that implicit `var` typing can only be used for local variables, i.e. C# doesn't support implicit typing of method return types (unlike functional languages like Scala, where the compiler in most instances can also infer the return type of a method).

Comment: no it is not anonymous datatype , it is of type what the type will be returned from the right hand side of **=** . For Example, ``var i = 1;`` , now `i` is of type **int**

Comment: @FaizanRabbani `var` means: Compiler figures it out. It can be anonymous or a built-in type, but it will be strongly typed.

Comment: this is anonymous type : ``new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" }`` but `var` will inherit whatever the type on right hand side , and yes in this case it is anonymous type but not every time it is anonymous

Comment: @FaizanRabbani you are misreading that page. You need to use var when declaring an anonymous type, but that's not what var *is*.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani var is **not** anonymous datatype.. it just saves you from few keystrokes, and only in some cases is necessary, where the type is compiler generated (not sure if it should be called anonymous, because many languages have explicit meaning for anonymous types.. where as C# doesn't use the term Anonymous type.. not in the same way AFAIK).

Comment: Okay. I know C# is strongly typed language.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani: `var` in C# is more synonymous to `auto` in C++. In both cases, the programmer does not need to specify what the exact type is, it is inferred by using the type of the value that is assigned to it. It doesn't mean it is anonymous.

Comment: @JeffMercado I wrote `auto autoint = 6;` it gave me an error: `missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani: [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is a C++11 feature... you need to use a compiler that supports it and have it enabled.

Comment: @JeffMercado Currently I am using VS 2008.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani: then it is definitely not supported. 2008 only supports C++03 for the most part.

Comment: Okay. I am reading about `auto`. Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani C# is not *just* static typed, either; see `dynamic` ;p

Answer (score 7):

- In an unsafe context, the equivalent of C++ `void*` in C# is `void*`. Any data pointer type can be assigned to a `void*`.
- In a safe context, `object` is (loosely) the corresponding concept. Any class/interface/struct instance can be assigned to it.
- The equivalent of C# `var` in C++ is `auto`. When used to declare and initialize a local variable, it acts as the type of the expression assigned to that variable, if that is possible.

Comment: And to be clear, primitive types such as `int` are structs too in C#, so they too can be assigned to variables of type `object`.

Comment: minor nitpick... but function pointers cannot be (safely) assigned to `void*` that's undefined behavior. That said POSIX requires it so as a consequence most compilers support it, albeit with a warning if you have turned those up.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with c++ void pointer:

```
void * val = (void *) 7;
val = (void *) "Abcd";
```

But you cannot do this with c# var:

```
var val = 7;
val = "abcd";
```

This will throw an error.

### Update

If you want to achieve similar behavior of `void *` you can use `dynamic`.

```
dynamic val = (dynamic) 7;
val = (dynamic) "ABC";
```

When `var` is used, the actual type of the variable is determined at compile time. But, when `dynamic` is used, the actual type of the variable is determined at run time.

Comment: Okay, yes it will. But what is `anonymous datatype` then?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani that just means a type that the compiler has created in the background for you that you cannot explicitly refer to by name (it is unpronounceable); here you *must* use one of `var`, `object` or `dynamic`, because you don't have any other options: you can't use the actual name *because you don't know it*. For example: `var foo = new { Id = 123, Name = "abc" };`

Comment: but that would be `unsafe`